# How to retrieve a HTML tag from a column

Tags: html, asp.net, sql, xml

I have an SQL table which has a column that includes some HTML/XML tag. Here is an example:

```
<root><Physicians><name>John Helsinki, MD</name>
<picture><img src="/uploadedImages/svr/physicians/images/John web.jpg?n=9059" alt="Helsinki, John Photo" /></picture>
<gender>M</gender>
<specialty><a href="/WA/test.aspx?56" title="Eye Care">OPT</a></specialty>
<specialty2></specialty2>
<specialty3></specialty3>
<additional_specialty></additional_specialty>
</Physicians>
</root>
```

How can I extract the `<img>` tag that is in between `<picture></picture>`?

I know I can use the `LIKE` keyword in SQL but I am not sure how to proceed...

Comment: If you want to do this with SQL, which database product are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XPath taking advantage of the columns type - XML

```
declare @thing XML
set @thing = '<root><Physicians><name>John Helsinki, MD</name>
<picture><img src="/uploadedImages/svr/physicians/images/John web.jpg?n=9059" alt="Helsinki, John Photo" /></picture>
<gender>M</gender>
<specialty><a href="/WA/test.aspx?56" title="Eye Care">OPT</a></specialty>
<specialty2></specialty2>
<specialty3></specialty3>
<additional_specialty></additional_specialty>
</Physicians>
</root>'

SELECT @thing.query('/root/Physicians/picture/img')
```

An alternative way of doing it via a table:

```
DECLARE @XmlTable TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL, XmlData XML)
INSERT INTO @XmlTable 
        (ID, XmlData)
VALUES
        (1, '<root><Physicians><name>John Helsinki, MD</name>
<picture><img src="/uploadedImages/svr/physicians/images/John web.jpg?n=9059" alt="Helsinki, John Photo" /></picture>
<gender>M</gender>
<specialty><a href="/WA/test.aspx?56" title="Eye Care">OPT</a></specialty>
<specialty2></specialty2>
<specialty3></specialty3>
<additional_specialty></additional_specialty>
</Physicians>
</root>')

select XmlData.query('/root/Physicians/picture/img') from @XmlTable
```

This takes advantage of the [query method](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191474.aspx) available on any XML variable type thus in this context:

```
select [column].query('/root/Physicians/picture/img') from [table]
```

Comment: The `@thing` is dynamic and never for the same person.

Comment: That works great. Can I insert a SELECT statement to get the @thing instead of hard coding the string value?

Comment: The column will constantly change so hard coding it, even in a table is not an option for me unfortunately. I was trying something like this: `set @thing = (SELECT [column] FROM [database].[dbo].[table])` but it was giving me an error.

Comment: I have it like this: `declare @thing XML
set @thing = SELECT [content_html].query('/root/Physicians/picture/img') from [Database].[dbo].[table]
SELECT @thing.query('/root/Physicians/picture/img')` but I get an error: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.`

Comment: @SiKni8 You don't need the intermediate variable to get the result you can just run: SELECT [content_html].query('/root/Physicians/picture/img') 
from [Database].[dbo].[table]

Comment: I figured so I went ahead and ran it and I get this error: `Cannot find either column "content_html" or the user-defined function or aggregate "content_html.query", or the name is ambiguous.`

Comment: @SiKni8 What is the data type of your column - content-html? The type must be set to XML in the table designer

Comment: It is `ntext` data type. I have like 200 rows in my table and want to display all 200 rows with just the `<img ... />` tag stripped from the column `content_html`

Comment: It is a sensitive table. I am wondering If I can copy the column to a temporary table and assign it as XML and then use it?

Comment: If there is a way to copy the column to an new table with the XML data type and then query that using a Stored Procedure?

Comment: @SiKni8 Create a new table and set the column as NVARCHAR(MAX) and then import the xml data into the new table. Then you do a cast - SELECT CAST(newNvarcharColumn AS XML) which means you can update a newly created XML column or you can say CAST(newNvarcharColumn AS XML).query('etc...

Comment: Took your idea and used the existing query to get it to work :)... Here is my final query: `SELECT CAST([content_html] AS XML).query('/root/Physicians/picture/img') FROM [dbase].[dbo].[content] WHERE [folder_id] = '188'`

Comment: I will but have to wait 11 minutes. One concern (I can ask a new question if need be) is what if there are more than one image tag and I want to insert each tag in it's own row?